# How to create the same algorithm for a different cell, but add to same cell

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, named-ranges, gs-vlookup

I'm a real newbie to this. This is VERY long winded. I want to do this exact piece of code but for `L16,17,18` and `19` (currently for `L15`) All of these return to `L20`, But past `L15`, I can't get them into `L20`... This is really hard to word!

```
=IF(L15=1,+5,IF(L15=2,+4,IF(L15=3,+3,IF(L15=4,+2,IF(L15=5,+2,IF(L15=6,+2,IF(L15=7,+1,IF(L15=8,+1,IF(L15=9,+1,IF(L15=10,+1))))))))))
```

Breakdown: this: `=IF(L15=1,+5)` is interpreting a race. If I come 1st, I gain 5 Points. and so on (see above code)

would greatly appreciate the help!

Just to confirm, I am using Google Sheets.

Comment: i would *highly* recommend using index/match for this, having a master "first, second, third" table, with the associated points.  Then your formula will look like `=Index(TableOutput,Match(L15,TableSearchArray,0))`

Comment: Having only used Google Sheets for a day, How would I come about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comment as an answer:

Table looks like

```
Place    Points
1        5
2        4
3        3
4        2
5        1
```

Highlight the COLUMN for Place and name the range as "Place", same for points as "Points".

Your formula would look like:

```
=Index(Points,Match(L15,Place,0))
```

---

Related to this being updated to include "google sheets", I do not know if the named range will work there, but the formula would work.  You would then need to use actual ranges, rather than named ranges, such that:

```
=Index(Table!B$2:B$6,Match(L15,Table!A$2:A$6,0))
```

Comment: Okay, so here is the code i've used: =INDEX(Table!C38:C47,Match(L15:L19,Table!B38:B47,0)) But unsure on how it works, I have feedback of #N/A

Comment: Okay, so I have L15 to work, but not for L16,17,18,19. Not sure on how to get this in there :) Really appreciate the help so far.

Comment: @KarlanParker you would need to make fixed your table references.  Will update post to include the "$"

Comment: GREAT! I've added the $ signs, and got it all working. however. If i move the results table *(not the range table)* It loses the values on there, and shows #N/A, Do you know how this is fixed?

Comment: This also happens when I create a duplicate (which I need)

Comment: @KarlanParker I would ask you to look at what the references are in the formulas once your table is moved.  You may need to fix more of your formula, e.g., to lock the column you would put "$" before the column label so Table!$A$2:$A$6.  It's odd that is happening when you move your data... not sure if that's tied to Google Sheets, as that shouldn't happen with Excel

Comment: life saver :) fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming L15 is one of various different positions in a race and below that are other relevant positions then please try:

```
=(L15<11)+(L15<7)+(L15<4)+(L15<3)+(L15<2)
```

copied down no further than position 10.

Answer (score 0):

a one-cell solution would be much easier:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L15:L, {1, 5; 
                                      2, 4; 
                                      3, 3; 
                                      4, 2; 
                                      5, 1}, 2, 1)))
```

[image: 0]

**alternative approaches: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**